# I want to get user information multiple times

Tags: java, android

I am working on a android project and basically its function is to serve as a platform for teachers to create quizzes in their android phone and for students to take the quiz also from their android phone.

Here is what I have done so far. For the teacher, I was already able to get information about how many parts does the quiz that they are creating have,the number of items for each parts, and the nature of each parts(Multiple Choice,Identification,etc.).

But my problem is how will I be able to get the information about the questions multiple times based on how many items they enter on each parts? I mean, they will have to enter the questions several times based on the number of items right? How will I be able to do that? I am thinking of this pseudo code:

```
for (int i=0; i < numberoftest; i++){
for (int x=0; i < numberofitems; x++){
user will enter questions and answers in a edittexts-->get user information 
through a button click-->store it somewhere--->clear the contents of 
edittexts
}}
```

I am looking for the better approach. Thanks!

Comment: Are you storing the question in a a sqlite o are you using directly networking?

Comment: Don't make the user count the questions/test before making them, What if he/she miscount?  Is better to use arraylist over array for this cases, when you have to iterate inside the arraylist use the iterator and finally save them in sqlite or database online with serial id's to store the order of the questions/tests.